# Using SSIS to move a SQL Server table to a specific MySQL folder

Tags: mysql, sql, ssis, ado.net, connection

I'm moving a SQL Server table from SQL Server 2008 R2 to MySQL on my `c:\ drive` by using SSIS.

In SSIS, I have created ADO.Net source and destination connections with a 64 bit unicode driver I downloaded and have managed to successfully to transfer the data from SQL Server to a newly created MySQL table.
However, even though all rows were copied successfully, the table doesn't show up in the MySQLdatabase with my other tables.  SSIS put the table in a different directory from the one where the database tables are located.  I don's see how to change the location.  When I'm selecting a table in SSIS for the data to go to, it doesn't show the right list of tables.

It's showing tables located in  `c:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql` while my database tables are located in `c:\xampp\mysql\mydb`.  How can I access these new tables, or direct SSIS to use a different path?

Comment: Did you setup the appropriate connection manager in the ADO.NET Destination data flow item?

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple MySQL installs running and SSIS is connecting to the wrong one?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.  I have a local instance of mySQL.  As Ivan suggested, it is a problem with the connection I setup. I didn't see anyway to change that, since when you look at the connections offered in SSIS after picking "NEW" to create a new connection in the ADO.Net setup, there's a drop down menu with my existing connection  and a few others but that's it, so what you have to do is opt for creating a new connection string, and in that set of menus I was able to add a new connection (the string is built for you), so when I redid the connection, and moved the next table it went into the database.  So, that worked.
Just as an aside, Of course, I found that the transformation will only succeed if you run the following statement in MySQL: "SET GLOBAL sql_mode='ANSI' once you've started up MySQL from the XAMP control panel.